# How to convert this "Wed, 10 Jun 2020 10:16:24 GMT" to this "2020-05-10T12:30:45" datetimestr format

Tags: scala, date, time, format

I'm trying this but im getting exception at parse

```
{
  val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")
  val format_input = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z")
    format.format(
      format_input.parse(
        "Wed, 10 Jun 2020 10:16:24 GMT"
      )
    )
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the old and outdated `SimpleDate` library?

Comment: No, im just a newbie with scala and java libraries, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd highly recommend using the newer `java.time.LocalDateTime` utility in place of the decrepit `SimpleDate` library.

Because your input format is one of the predefined `DateTimeFormatter` formats, and your desired output format is the same as the `LocalDateTime` default format, the solution becomes quite simple.

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter._
import java.time.LocalDateTime

LocalDateTime.parse("Wed, 10 Jun 2020 10:16:24 GMT"
                   ,RFC_1123_DATE_TIME).toString

//res0: String = 2020-06-10T10:16:24
```